# FileNotFoundException with Urlconnection Get Request

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection, urlconnection, httpsurlconnection

Doing `GET` request with `URLConnection`. code is here

```
java.net.URL url = new java.net.URL(requestUrl);
        URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
        is = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
```

getting `java.io.FileNotFoundException` whereas requested url is correct. i think it may be https ssl certificate issue. if anyone else got this issue and resolved please update.

Comment: What's your `requestURL`? Have you done something to resolve HTTPS SSL Certificate issue?

Comment: can you please guide me how to add ssl certificate for https requests

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Encode your parameter to create an URL for request.Unsupported
>   character in parameter value may cause to exceptions it can be a white space also.

```
    String url = "http://url.com";
    String charset = "UTF-8";  // Or in Java 7 and later, use the constant: java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name()
    String param1 = "value1";
    String param2 = "value2";
    // ...

    String query = String.format("param1=%s&param2=%s", 
         URLEncoder.encode(param1, charset), 
         URLEncoder.encode(param2, charset));

    URLConnection connection = new URL(url + "?" + query).openConnection();
    connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", charset);
    InputStream response = connection.getInputStream();
// ...
```

[Courtsey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/using-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests)